# chown does not change ownership

Tags: 19.04

I have a tree of files that somehow have been become owed by root:plugdev.
When I run the command `sudo chown -R jgossage:jgossage directory` no ownership is changed. How am I supposed to change the ownership of these files? Permissions are 0770 on all files and directories. I am using Ubuntu 19.04 desktop.

Comment: How is it mounted? `mount` or https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld

Comment: It was mounted with mount.

Comment: I meant for you to show the output of the `mount` command for the drive

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake. I had forgotten that the files were on an NTFS volume where the owner cannot be changed.